# iPad DecimalPad Entry - any good options?

Tags: ios, ipad, text, keyboard, numeric

iOS has the "UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad" keyboard type - for numeric entry - which works for the iPhone, but does not appear to do so for the iPad. I need a keyboard entry with just numbers and a decimal point (same as what UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad gives) and I have 2 questions:

1. Is there anyway to get UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad to work on an iPad?
2. If not, then has any one built a custom modal, or popover entry screen, that gives the same functionality?

NOTE: My main concern here is not input validation - but ease of use.

Any assistance is appreciated!
--Mike C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a purely numeric keyboard on the iPad, you'll have to build it yourself and assign an instance of your custom view to the `inputView` property of your text field or text view.

Comment: It turns out that my client can live with the iPad numeric keyboard (with other symbols) - but given my question - I think the inputView is the correct response.